# Spring java.lang.IllegalStateException:Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-cloud-netflix

We have written a web application using spring {boot, security and cloud (Netflix API)}.

In this web application we are addressing requirement of authentication and authorization via JWT token (reference from https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java).

With our current implementation we are seeing exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed"

We have also tested without security config and in that case we are able to see JSP output without any exception.

Much appreciated if we get some expert comment here in case you see we are doing anything incorrectly.

Snippet from console

```
subscriptionID : 7abdfcd3-93f4-452f-ae23-9b7dea1762cc
month : 4
year : 2017
2017-07-04 09:02:44.274 ERROR 8996 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2998) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2437) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:594) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:539) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.initialize(PageContextImpl.java:137) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalGetPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:60) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.jsp.invoice_jsp._jspService(invoice_jsp.java:100) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at com.ekanna.martmonkey.web.security.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:58) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:84) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.ekanna.martmonkey.web.security.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:58) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:590) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:524) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:160) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at com.ekanna.martmonkey.web.security.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:58) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.ekanna.martmonkey.web.security.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:58) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Security Config

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;
@Autowired
private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception
{
    JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    jwtAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return jwtAuthenticationFilter;
}
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
}
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
{
    List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviderList = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
    authenticationProviderList.add(jwtAuthenticationProvider());
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new ProviderManager(authenticationProviderList);
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider()
{
    JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider();
    return jwtAuthenticationProvider;
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
{
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/*.html", "/favicon.ico", "/**/*.html", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js")
            .permitAll().antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
}
```

}

Auth Provider

In our authentication provider we making a call to remote API for validating JWT token.
But here for investigation purpose we have commented out that call and assuming token validation is successfull.

```
import com.web.security.services.RemoteSecurityAPI;
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{
@Autowired
RemoteSecurityAPI remoteSecurityAPI;
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
{
    final JwtAuthenticationToken jwtToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication;

    // Call security rest API for validating token.
    //final MyJwtUser jwtUser = remoteSecurityAPI.validateJWTToken(jwtToken.getToken());
    final JwtUser jwtUser = new JwtUser(
            null, "98816123456", "amit", "jain",
            "a@a.com", "123456",
            mapToGrantedAuthorities(), true,
            null
    );
    if (jwtUser != null)
    {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtUser.getAuthorities();
        final Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtUser, null, authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        return auth;
    }
    throw new BadCredentialsException("Token is not valid...");
}
private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapToGrantedAuthorities(
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
)
{
    List<GrantedAuthority> authority = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    Iterator<? extends GrantedAuthority> i = authorities.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        final LinkedHashMap<String, String> name = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) i.next();
        final SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(name.get("authority"));
        authority.add(simpleAuthority);
    }
    return authority;
}

private static List<GrantedAuthority> mapToGrantedAuthorities()
{
    List<GrantedAuthority> authority = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    authority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    return authority;
}
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> c)
{
    return true;
}
}
```

invoice.jsp

```
<h1>Welcome to UUID Generator, Your UUID : ${model.invoice}</h1>
```

Thank in Advance...

Comment: In exception log snippet if we see there are multiple time call for our custom filter JwtAuthenticationFilter.

Comment: We tried with rest flow which has also failed with same error
@RestController
public class InvoiceRestController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/invoicesrest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String invoiceRest()
    {
        return "invoice-rest";
    }
}

Comment: In debug logs we can see two time request is called with different paths o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/invoicesrest] and DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and found out that `allowSessionCreation` flag is set to true in `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

```
@Autowired
public JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
    setAllowSessionCreation(false); // This will stop creating session
}
```

See if you can supply success & failure handler in your `JwtAuthenticationFilter`.

```
protected JwtAuthenticationFilter build JwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    JwtAuthenticationFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter(matcher, successHandler, failureHandler);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}
```

Then set those handler

```
public JwtAuthenticationFilter(String defaultProcessUrl, AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler,
                                  AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
    super(defaultProcessUrl);
    setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler); // Respond as 200, instead of 302
    setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler); // Respond as 401
}
```